# Removing all the \vspace{} commands from the document

Tags: vspace

(textstudio)
How can I get rid of all the \vspace{}* commands from my document automatically, without having to remove one by one ?
I was using it in and out of my equations' throughout the whole document but they told me I shouldn't use it.

*Actually it's not all, but only after the *introduction* chapter of the document, when the equations start to appear.

Thanks in advance and sorry if that's too simple to solve.

Comment: Do you mean literally `\vspace{}` or various instances of `\vspace{xxx}` with different values of `xxx`?  TeXstudio has a find and replace function which allows you to replace all, or all within a selection etc. You can make the Replace bar visible below the Find bar by choosing `Searching->Replace` from the Edit menu.

Comment: Well, I'd probably do `sed '/\\chapter{Introduction}/,$s/\\vspace{}\*/g' <filename> > <filename2>`. Or the equivalent in Kile's find-and-replace.

Comment: Welcome on tex.stackexchange.// this seems to be more an editor question than a LaTeX question. With a decent editor, inluding TeXstudio a find&replace using regular expression would be the most obvious solution.// An alternatve would perform a find&replace from `\vspace{` to ,`\foobar` and define the later as `\newcommand{\foobar}[1]{}`.

Comment: What @cfr said, but `\\vspace{[^}]*}` instead of `\\vspace{}\*` (assuming you want to remove all `\vspace{xxx}`, not all literal `\vspace{}` which would've been low level TeX errors).

Comment: @Skillmon It wasn't clear to me whether that was why the OP had been told not to use it. On OverLeaf, people tend to just ignore the errors. Otherwise, maybe it should be `\\vspace\*{[^}]*}` since the `*` in the original would be literal?

Comment: @cfr I take it that the `*` in the question is denoting a footnote and doesn't mean the starred variant of `\vspace`.

Comment: @Skillmon Ooh. I missed that completely. Oops.

Comment: Thank you all for the help ;)